# Python | Insert Two Items in a List per Iteration with One-Liner

Tags: python, for-loop

Is it possible to insert in a list 2 items with one-liner?
For example, get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` by something like `[ x, x+1 for x in [1, 3]]`

Comment: can you provide a real case for this?

Comment: I've got a dataframe with columns ["12-18 Salary", "12-18 Penetration", "12-18 Views", "19-25 Salary", "19-25 Penetration", "19-25 Views", ...] and I've got a list of age groups ["12-18", "19-25", ...]. I want to select "Salary" and "Views" columns for all age groups, i.e. I need to get a list ["12-18 Salary", "12-18 Views", "19-25 Salary", "19-25 Views", ...]. I want to generate this listed based on age groups list in one line

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this. Instead you can use a generator expression within `itertools.chain.from_iterable` in order to chain the iterable items or use a nested list comprehension (which is not as optimized as *`chain.from_iterable`* since you have to create the items then unpack them with another loop).

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 5)]
>>> 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(i for i in l))
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

In python 3.5+ you can unpack the iterables within a list like following but still not at iteration time.

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = (3, 5)
>>> 
>>> [*a, *b]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for sublist in [ [x, x+1] for x in [1, 3] ] for item in sublist]
```